# SSRS Export to Excel not working through VPN (Juniper SA4000)

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, juniper

We have a SharePoint (MOSS 2007 on Win2003 R2) with SSRS reports (from SQL 2005) embedded in it.

When we connect to the SharePoint portal through our VPN (firewall is Juniper SA4000) and using Internet Explorer (6, 7, and 8) and try to export any SSRS report under Excel, we get an error message:

```
Internet Explorer cannot download .
Internet Explorer was not able to open the internet site. The requested site is either unavailable or cannot be found. Please try again later.
```

When not using the VPN (LAN from the office), everything (exporting under Excel) works fine.
When using Firefox through the VPN, it works fine. 
When exporting to any other format (pdf or text or whatever), everything is fine under both IE and FF.

Our firewall people suspect something in SSRS/MOSS/Office. Our MOSS consultants suspect something in the firewall Juniper SA4000.

When using Fiddler and when not connected through VPN, I see the following traffic once i click on the "Export button": 
(Response was a request for client credentials)

```
GET /ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=j1pqbvbqkb34qf45fhlgnx55&ControlID=733607a7d607476abb1e6b8794202158&Culture=127&UICulture=9&ReportStack=1&OpType=Export&FileName=Product+Application+Report&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=EXCEL HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,fr-be;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB5; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; MS-RTC LM 8; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: r1frchcurdb01.r1.group.corp

HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1656
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2009 09:25:21 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

then (Generic Response successful):

```
GET /ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=j1pqbvbqkb34qf45fhlgnx55&ControlID=733607a7d607476abb1e6b8794202158&Culture=127&UICulture=9&ReportStack=1&OpType=Export&FileName=Product+Application+Report&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=EXCEL HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,fr-be;q=0.5
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB5; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; InfoPath.2; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; MS-RTC LM 8; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: r1frchcurdb01.r1.group.corp
Authorization: Negotiate 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

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2009 09:25:21 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYGgMIGdoAMKAQChCwYJKoZIgvcSAQICooGIBIGFYIGCBgkqhkiG9xIBAgICAG9zMHGgAwIBBaEDAgEPomUwY6ADAgEXolwEWm70xlMp4oj/PyvriNMeNDigow6/MX2DpaYQdBfGkiF0Dcc323tHLRBxBL03QpvwdGBxZGAJI6V1G8sc/lVBzhlCNsZkbJcNfnMNgOgc7UPrz+ZVav/EVm3sDQ==
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Product Application Report.xls"
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Mon, 08 Jun 2009 09:24:21 GMT
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Content-Length: 23012
```

When using the VPN, I see no traffic in Fiddler and the error message is displayed before anything else.

Update 17/06/2009:
I could get a hand on some logs from our SA4000. Maybe this could help more.

```
Info    PTR23232    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Start Policy [WEBURL/PROTOCOL] evaluation for resource http://<DB server>:80/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=rua1g355tic24245f2e13lim&ControlID=44168efcd36e461493f7a69962580b91&Culture=127&UICulture=9&ReportStack=1&OpType=Export&FileName=Product+Application+Report&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=EXCEL 
Info    PTR23233    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Applying Policy [Enable HTTP 1.1]... 
Info    PTR23240    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Resource filter [http://nsrvnts2:80/*] does not match 
Info    PTR23240    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Resource filter [http://nsrvnts3:80/*] does not match 
Info    PTR23233    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Applying Policy [Disable HTTP 1.1]... 
Info    PTR23239    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Action [HTTP 1.0] is returned 
Info    PTR23234    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Policy [Disable HTTP 1.1] applies to resource 
Info    PTR23308    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Skip Policy [WEBURL/COMPRESSION] evaluation because Compression option is not enabled 
Info    PTR23232    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Start Policy [WEBURL/WEBPDSID] evaluation for resource http://<DB server>:80/ReportServer/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?ExecutionID=rua1g355tic24245f2e13lim&ControlID=44168efcd36e461493f7a69962580b91&Culture=127&UICulture=9&ReportStack=1&OpType=Export&FileName=Product+Application+Report&ContentDisposition=OnlyHtmlInline&Format=EXCEL 
Info    PTR23233    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Applying Policy [Corporate BI Portal]... 
Info    PTR23240    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Resource filter [http://<SharePoint>:80/*] does not match 
Info    PTR23240    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - Resource filter [http://<SharePoint>/*] does not match 
Info    PTR23235    2009/06/15 17:22:38 - <SA4000> - [<SA4000 IP>] - <user>[SA4000 group names] - No Policy applies to resource
```

Any tip welcome. :)

Comment: By "no traffic", I assume you mean there was no response from the server after the HTTP request for the file is sent? Do you have access to the IIS logs for that time period? Does the request reach the IIS server when you're connecting through VPN?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: Still not solved and my schedule does not allow me to work on this right now. :(

Comment: We have upgraded to the most recent version of these SA4000 and still have the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found the solution, finally.

We had to:

- add the target server to the cache options of the Juniper so that information from that server would NOT be cached;
- change the Juniper parameter about headers from "smart" to "unchanged".

And now it works ...

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to inspect the traffic while you're on the corporate LAN, and compare the traffic through the VPN / Juniper firewall. You could try [Fiddler with Firefox](http://javaswamy.blogspot.com/2007/02/using-fiddler-with-firefox.html) and IE as another comparison. Hopefully you'll see a difference that will point you in the right direction...

I am *guessing* this has something to do with authentication differences between Firefox and IE, and that there's a proxy breaking IE's method of authentication.

You could also try changing security on your SharePoint site, is it possible to open up a blank report for a brief period of time (ie, anonymous access allowed, no Integrated Security / NTFS issues possible)?

Comment: I upvoted your answer for the Fiddler idea and updated my question with the info.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, some Juniper VPNs cannot delegate address assignments to your organization's DHCP servers, so depending on how you're DNS is secured, clients may not be able to register their host names correctly, which can break Kerberos. Also, if you're using a reverse proxy to get to the Sharepoint farm, there are numerous ways to implement that in a way that breaks Kerberos.

The first thing I would try is to make sure that you allow negotiation for auth so that the browser will downgrade to NTLM or Basic/Digest auth. If that works, you can start yelling at the VPN guys, who may or may not be able to do something about it.